# How to stop Google Script running infinetly

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail

I have accidentally started a GmailApp script with infinite loop and now i m receiving bulk mail. I had set an alias for my account and been receiving mail from alias account.

I tried to stop the script by:

1. Revoked the access to the script
2. Deleted the alias as well, no success yet
3. Deleting the script but not working, still receiving the mails

Now i have no idea what to do. I last 30 mins i have received around 500 mail and dont know how to stop these script.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that the script is sending you bulk email because it can send a maximum of 100 emails in a day while you received 500 in 30 minutes.

If you could look into the email headers, it will give you some idea about where these emails are originating from.